# What exactly is the meaning of the word "Feddy" here?

Tags: meaning, etymology, slang

I've been playing a game and after completing a mission, one character ask to another the following:

> How you doing on the feddy?

From the context, I assume that it's somehow related to money, but I'm not sure-it's an odd word!
The only site I found it was on Urban Dictionary.

My question is, what does *feddy* really mean here, and how did it come to take on that meaning?

([Here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rSVzt9wN8UM) the video that shows some more context.)

Answer (score 1):

***Feddy*** is slang for ***money***:

> (US black) money ([Green's dict of slang](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/zuhecsi))

Not sure how credible the etymology is, but [Urban dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=feddy) gives exactly the example in your video and says it means:

> Money, ***short for the Spanish word "feria"*** meaning money.
>
> - How you doing on the feddy?
>   I'm kinda short, you know.

*Feddy* might indeed come from Spanish and Words Matter gives another spelling:

> ***Fetti*** 
> A gross mispronunciation of the Spanish word ***feria***, which in Mexico is used to mean ***coins***. But maybe the term is also the result of the confetti-like image of money pouring from the sky when someone “makes it rain”.

[Writings explained](https://writingexplained.org/slang-for-money) agrees:

> ***Fetti***: Money in general; originates from ***feria***, the Spanish term for *money*.

Comment: Intriguing. I would have assumed that it comes from the "Federal Reserve Note" which appears on American paper money.